# Access WhatsApp and transfer to new phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I got a new SIM card, but never changed it in WhatsApp to the new number. Now my phone is broken (screen is broken) and I cannot retrieve my WhatsApp account as I would first have to change to the new number from the broken phone. I don't have the old SIM card.

Here is [the official WhatsApp help center for lost and stolen phones](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/24460358/?category=5245246), but it only works if the new SIM card has the same number.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The only way to move messages to your new phone would be if you somehow access your old phone. But, if you want to save the 'account', then have in mind that there is no real difference between switching your number on the old phone as apposed to simply registering your new number on a new phone. The reason for that is: even if you switch numbers on old device people sending messages to old number will NOT get redirected to new number. So the only difference is that you will have to be re-added to the groups you were on. If you were the only admin of a group that would be a problem.

Comment: My suggestion is, to email WhatsApp and ask them to deactivate your account so that people sending messages there will at least know that they got the wrong number. In general i suggest not to use WhatsApp with a number that you no longer have access to. Because you never know when someone will get your number (after three months of not paying for a number, the phone company could give it away) and activate their account with it

Comment: Thats very true @Abochur i will do that

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the old SIM card, try to install WhatsApp on the new phone using the old SIM and it will automatically restore your contact to your new phone. After that, you can change to your new SIM card.

Comment: unfortunately, no sim card and new sim card has a different number